# Facebook Realtime Updates: charged payments not received

Tags: facebook, payment, real-time-updates

After subscribing to FB Realtime updates on payment's object i have found, that FB doesn't notify my callback url on successful payment. But in docs i have found (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment/ chapter "Asynchronous Confirmation"):

"You can get additional confirmation of a successful payment by subscribing to Realtime Updates for the Payment object and specifying a callback URL. Whenever there's a change in the actions field of a payment made in your app, Facebook will notify the specified callback..."

That means, if payment was in one action (charged and successful), subscription on payment object will not be notified with payment_id?

Yes, payment was confirmed by js callback and stored, but i think fb realtime should sent notification with payment_id to me, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have subscribed to the "Fields" "actions" and "disputes"?

I get updates on all successful purchases (along with failed ones.)

Comment: Yep, if set "fields" to "actions" FB start sending notification.But it is not obviously, because permissions object not required setting **fields** value. Thank you